# Displaying a view as a lightbox in razor application

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

i have an asp.net mvc4 application with razor.

**View.Cshtml**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
          Concept technologique
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @foreach(Features_Management.Models.First_Attempt fa in Model)
    {
        <tr style="font-size: 12px; padding:0px;">
            <td>
                  @Html.Raw(@fa.Concept)
            </td>
            <td> 
                @Html.ActionLink("Donner votre avis","", new { id_element =  @fa.Id_element})
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

I need to display the same view in a `Lightbox` when i click into the `ActionLink`.

How can i do this? Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try something already?

Comment: i tried this http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/ but it is a simple demo that help to display an image not a view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/) (alternative to lightbox)

Add this in page(.cshtml)

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery
                                     /1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css"
  media="screen" />
```

MVC Helper code

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Donner votre avis","", new { id_element =  @fa.Id_element,
    @class='iframe'})
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.iframe).fancybox();    
}
```

[Read more](http://fancybox.net/howto)